# Why the cursor doesn't stop in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I run the following code to perform my stored procedure in SQL Server, but after this cursor run and my column in stored procedure is updated, this cursor doesn't stop and continues to execute. Can you give me some idea?

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @id AS INT
DECLARE @asin AS NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @date AS DATE

BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
                        SELECT id, asin, ReviewDate 
                        FROM software

    OPEN @MyCursor 

    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @id , @asin, @date

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC [dbo].[SP_Review_Group_Agreemnet] @id, @asin, @date
        --print @id

        FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @id, @asin, @date
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

The stored procedure looks like this:

```
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Review_Group_Agreemnet]  
    @id AS INT, 
    @asin AS NVARCHAR(50), 
    @date AS DATE   -- @Product_Second_Date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @number_of_day AS INT 

    SET @number_of_day = (SELECT dbo.fn_date_copy(@asin, 1)) 

    DECLARE @after_day AS DATE
    SET @after_day = DATEADD(d, @number_of_day, @date)

    DECLARE @previous_day AS DATE
    SET @previous_day = DATEADD(d, -@number_of_day, @date)

    DECLARE @avg_prev AS FLOAT
    SET @avg_prev= (SELECT ROUND(AVG(overall), 2) 
                    FROM Software 
                    WHERE (ReviewDate BETWEEN @previous_day AND @date) 
                      AND asin = @asin AND id != @id)

    DECLARE @avg_after AS FLOAT
    SET @avg_after = (SELECT ROUND(AVG(overall), 2) 
                      FROM Software 
                      WHERE (ReviewDate BETWEEN @date AND @after_day) 
                        AND asin = @asin AND id != @id)     

    UPDATE dbo.software 
    SET Review_Group_Agreement = t.agreement 
    FROM 
        (SELECT
             id, 
             (CASE WHEN ABS(overall - @avg_after) <= 1 OR
                        ABS(overall - @avg_prev) < 1 
                      THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
              END) AS agreement
         FROM 
             Software) AS t
    WHERE
        Software.id = t.id
END
```

and the function is:

```
USE [ReviewDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_date_copy]
     (@asin NVARCHAR(50), @baze AS INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DateDiff AS INT
    DECLARE @Quotient AS INT 
    DECLARE @Remainder AS INT 
    DECLARE @Number_of_Days AS INT 

    SET @DateDiff = (SELECT DATEDIFF(d, First_Date, Last_Date)  
                     FROM metaData 
                     WHERE asin = @asin)
    SET @Quotient = @DateDiff * @baze / 100
    SET @Remainder = @DateDiff * @baze % 100

    IF @Remainder != 0
       SET @Number_of_Days = @Quotient + 1
    ELSE
       SET @Number_of_Days = @Quotient

    RETURN @Number_of_Days
END
```

Finally the structure of the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Software]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [reviewerID] [nvarchar](28) NULL,
    [asin] [nvarchar](18) NULL,
    [reviewerName] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [helpful] [int] NULL,
    [overall] [float] NULL,
    [unixReviewTime] [int] NULL,
    [reviewTime] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [ReviewDate] [date] NULL,
    [Review_Group_Agreement] [int] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: thank you so much marc , i will do it but do u have any idea about the cursor problem?

Comment: From where and how are you calling this cursor?

Comment: shall i call? i didnt call the cursor i just execute it

Comment: Code works for me without call to  SP_Review_Group_Agreemnet

Comment: sorry Salmon Does the cursor stop? bcoz the select statement of me has 3 milion records

Comment: Does the stored procedure modify the `software` table? If so, change the cursor declaration to `SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR...`.

Comment: @shirin Yes cursor runs and exits as expected (without the call to the sp) problem is probably in/with the called sp.

Comment: yes exactly, it updates one column in software table . Ok i will try this thank you

Comment: @Salmon: ok thank you i will try to solve it but can u plz tell me how should i call cursor in on example?

Comment: @ Dan Guzman  : i changed to this but still the cursor doesn't stop. it updates my records but when all finish , still it is running ...

Comment: please provide test data for more help,i suggest you to run `select * from sys.dm_exec_requests`

Comment: Is a cursor really the best way to go for this? If youre going to be updating 3 millions records (? SQL doesn't have records), then that's not going to be great for performance. Especially if you're going to iterate each of them separately. A dataset approach would likely be far better; although you might still want to do it in batches.

Comment: @Shirin, add the create table (including indexes) and the update statement to your question. Ideally, we would like a complete script that reproduces the problem for troubleshooting. I suggested `FAST_FOWARD` since the default cursor is dynamic.

Comment: @Dan Guzman : I added SP, function and the structure of my table . It doesnt have index. Thank you

Comment: I inserted some test data and created the `metaData` table referenced by the function but could not reproduce the problem. Do you have sample data for both tables that will cause the issue?

Comment: @Dan yes i have but how can i put here? you know it can update all rows but it cannot stop from working, and the other problem is that each time it updates with different values

Comment: Try using a `STATIC` cursor.